# In Javascript, how to append string values to a JSON object, store it to a file, and retrieve/manipulate it later?

Tags: javascript, html, json, file, parsing

I am looking to do the following;

1. Load a CSV file into program memory into an array (abc, def, ghi etc.)
2. The user inputs text and clicks Add (say, def first, later ghi)
3. If a match is found, we create a new JSON array ("def": true, "ghi": true etc.)

Here is my code:

```js
csv = "abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno";

function myFunc(e) {

  var myArray = csv.split(',');
  console.log(myArray[0]);
  var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  if (myArray.indexOf(input) > -1) {
    //In the array -  So, we create a new file and add JSON content in it - how? - need to save it in this format - "abc": "true", "def": "true" and so on
    alert("The input you entered is valid.");

  } else {
    //Not in the array
    alert("The input you entered is not valid.");
  }
}

//How do I read the JSON object from the file later and then parse it back as a JSON object variable?
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="text" required id="userInput">
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Enter Input:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunc(this)">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You cannot do it in plain JavaScript. You have to use Node if you want to manipulate files

Comment: If files can't be written to, I would still like to see the logic of how to create the JSON object from the string as the question asks.

Comment: @Zac Look into `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`, they turn JSON strings into objects and vice versa. You can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`, but you won't have access to the actual file system in the browser. Think about what kind of security risk that would be if any website's JS code could read any file on your computer.

Comment: I wanted this code to be for a Cordova mobile app (so writing/reading files is not an issue) but noone was answering questions if posted as Cordova code so I posted it like this.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way for creating the JSON object

```js
var obj={'userInput':[]};
function myFunc(e)
{
obj.userInput.push(document.querySelector('#userInput').value)
console.log(obj)
}
```

```html
<form>   
    <div class="group">  
    <label>Enter Input:</label>
      <input type="text" required id="userInput">
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      
    </div>
     <div class="group">
       <input class="button" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunc(this)">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. I think the values entered have to be pushed to the obj object. However, on seeing its contents, Chrome console only shows "abc
{userInput: Array(1)}"
{userInput: Array(1)} - As you can see the Array(1)} isn't showing the values that were popped in to the obj. How to fix this?